# Accessing typescript type information in runtime

Tags: typescript, reflection, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using some interfaces exposed by a 3p library. Say something like:

```
interface A {
  c: number
  d: B 
}

interface B {
  e: number
  f: number
}
```

Is there any way to access this information dynamically? I know that typescript information is erased in runtime, but maybe something can be done, for example, parsing my AST and extracting the info.

If the classes were mine, I could approach the problem the other way around. Create the classes in code and generate the typescript types dynamically. For example, with [zod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod). But being a 3p library I cannot do it.

Basically, what I want to achieve is something like:

```
const a: A = // coming from external
console.log(beautified(a))

// A -->
// c: 1
// d: B
//    e: 3
//    f: 5

``

My motivation is to dynamically write some code.

Thanks
```